# Totally disconnected space and discrete topology

Tags: topological-groups

A topological space is totally disconnected if its only non empty connected sets are one point set. Is every totally disconnected space  discrete topology?

Comment: The rational numbers are totally disconnected but they are not discrete.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example $\mathbb{Q}$ with its order topology is totally disconnected, but not discrete.